# Using VS2013 and C-Sharp for Windows CE 5.0 Professional target platform

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-mobile, windows-ce, motorola

I need to develop one mini HTTP listener, on older Motorola rugged computer VC5090.

According to [manufacturers web site](http://www.motorolasolutions.com/US-EN/Business+Product+and+Services/Mobile+Computers/Vehicle-mounted+Computers/VC5090_US-EN), these are the specs of the platform and the development toolchain

- Intel, 32-bit XScale PXA270 processor at 624 MHz
- Microsoft Windows CE 5.0 Professional
- Microsoft Embedded Visual C++ Tools 4.0, TNT SMDK, VC5090 PSDK, Microsoft Visual Studio 2005

I would prefer using Visual Studio 2013 and develop in C-Sharp, with NET Compact Framework.

Is that possible and how should I configure dev environment and the project ? 
Which VS extensions / addons I need to install for the development?

According to [MS Support](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/947560), looks possible.

Comment: What advantages will be given for 2013 deving for 2005?

Comment: just convenience, as I am currently using it for other projects

Comment: Whilst this question targets VS2013, the same answer will apply

Comment: Thanks, will try with VS2008 first